# Finding The Laurent Series for $\sin(\frac{z}{1+z})$ at $z = -1.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I'm trying to find the Laurent Series for $\sin\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)$ centered around $z = -1.$ It seems to me that I should be considering the typical power series expansion of $\sin$, i.e.

$$\sin(w) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{w^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$

However, when I perform this with our current function, I see that

$$\sin\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k
\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(1+z)^{2k+1}(2k+1)!}.$$

I am not entirely sure what to do with $z^{k+1}.$ Are there some other things that I should be doing with this series to account for the singularity of $\frac{z}{1+z}$ at $z = -1$?

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
\sin\left(1-\frac1{1+z}\right)
&=\sin(1)\cos\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)-\cos(1)\sin\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)\\
&=\sin(1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)^{2k}-\cos(1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)^{2k+1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

$$\sin\left(\frac{z}{z+1}\right)=\sin\left(1-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)=\sin(1)\cos\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)-\cos(1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)$$